# How to store Binary files like Image, Font in java source file not on any file system or database

Tags: java, base64

I want to use font file and image in my java code. But I cannot store it in the database or in any file directory. I want to hard-code that file in .java file like I sometimes I hard-code base64 image in plsql procedure.
How to do this in java?

I want to generate pdf ID cards. so I have background image and font, only write the data on image and export. I will move only .class files on prod server, no jars.

Comment: Your Java code will likely be stored itself in a  Jar file, quite likely a runnable Jar file, and so best that all resources by the program, that are not going to be changed and that don't require a database, also be stored in the Jar file (so, no need for a database or file directory storage).

Comment: My code will not contain any jar file. I am using this code in Oracle EBS application and I will be moving only .class file to server.